# year movement using biblatex-chicago and biber

Tags: biber, biblatex-chicago

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{baggio} and \citet{anderson}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Content of the bib file**

```
@article{baggio,
Author = {R. Baggio and M. van Lambalgen and P. Hagoort},
Date-Added = {2014-02-06 14:22:28 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-06 14:24:02 +0100},
Journal = {Journal of {M}emory and {L}anguage},
Pages = {36--53},
Title = {Computing and Recomputing Discourse Models: An {ERP} Study},
Volume = {59},
Year = {2008}}

@book{anderson,
Address = {Mahwah, NJ},
Author = {J. R. Anderson},
Date-Added = {2014-02-05 15:27:59 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-05 16:10:22 +0100},
Publisher = {Lawrence {E}rlbaum {A}ssociates},
Title = {The Architecture of Cognition},
Year = {1983}}
```

**Required output**

[image]

I've referred the link [Put year into parentheses using biblatex-chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364515/put-year-into-parentheses-using-biblatex-chicago), but my requirement is something different.

I need to print the year should after volume number within parenthesis (for Book data, like the second in screenshot) and if no volume number (for Article data), then the year should come end of the reference with comma before...

Please advise....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` is a highly specialised style that does a lot of work to implement CMS rules as closely as possible. This means that it can be very tricky, tedious or close to impossible to make the style do something else (which it wasn't designed to do). `biblatex-chicago` is not meant to be customised beyond the options in its documentation. It is not a good choice as the basis of your custom style.

---

The style you seem to want for the bibliography is what you can get from the `biblatex-chicago` `notes` style.

But with the `notes` style you no longer get author-year citations. `\textcite`/`\citet` will no longer be of the form *Author (Year)*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{baggio,
  Author  = {R. Baggio and M. van Lambalgen and P. Hagoort},
  Journal = {Journal of Memory and Language},
  Pages   = {36--53},
  Title   = {Computing and Recomputing Discourse Models: An {ERP} Study},
  Volume  = {59},
  Year    = {2008},
}
@book{anderson,
  Address   = {Mahwah, NJ},
  Author    = {J. R. Anderson},
  Publisher = {Lawrence Erlbaum Associates},
  Title     = {The Architecture of Cognition},
  Year      = {1983},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill% just of this example, don't try this at home

\textcite{baggio} and \textcite{anderson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Anderson, J. R. The Architecture of Cognition. Mahwah, NJ: Lawrence Erlbaum Associates, 1983.]

---

**caveat emptor**

If you insist on mixing styles, which does not appear to be recommended or officially sanctioned by the CMS you could try something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=chicago-authordate, bibstyle=chicago-notes]{biblatex}
  \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    pagetracker=true,autocite=inline,alldates=comp,labeldateparts=true,
    citetracker=true,uniquename=minfull,useeditor=true,usetranslator=true,
    usenamec=true,alltimes=12h,urltime=24h,datecirca=true,datezeros=false,
    dateuncertain=true,timezones=true,compressyears=true,
    ibidtracker=constrict,sorting=cms,punctfont,cmslos=true,nodates,
    uniquelist=minyear,maxbibnames=10,minbibnames=7,sortcase=false,
    abbreviate=false,dateabbrev=false,avdate=true}

\providetoggle{cms@bookbibxref}
\providetoggle{cms@omitxrefdate}
\providetoggle{cms@postvol}
\providetoggle{cms@mtvolpunct}

\newbibmacro*{cjournal+ser+vol+num}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal+sub}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printlist[periodplace]{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}%
    {}%
    {\newcunit%
      \printfield[jourser]{series}%
      \newcunit}%\setunit*{\addspace}?
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}% need * here?
  \printfield[journum]{number}}% Moved eid for 17th ed.

\newbibmacro*{number+or+month}{%
  \iffieldundef{number}%
  {\usebibmacro{date}}%
  {\iftoggle{cms@numbermonth}%
    {\usebibmacro{date}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cmsyear}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{baggio,
  Author  = {R. Baggio and M. van Lambalgen and P. Hagoort},
  Journal = {Journal of Memory and Language},
  Pages   = {36--53},
  Title   = {Computing and Recomputing Discourse Models: An {ERP} Study},
  Volume  = {59},
  Year    = {2008},
}
@book{anderson,
  Address   = {Mahwah, NJ},
  Author    = {J. R. Anderson},
  Publisher = {Lawrence Erlbaum Associates},
  Title     = {The Architecture of Cognition},
  Year      = {1983},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{baggio} and \textcite{anderson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that I just loaded the two different citation and bibliography styles and copied missing definitions from `chicago-notes.cbx` until I no longer got errors. You will probably get more errors if you cite other (types of) works and will have to go back to `chicago-notes.cbx` to copy the relevant code. You will also have to double check the output.

**I absolutely cannot recommend this.**

---

It is slightly easier to mix note and author-date citations with `windycity`. But apparently `windycity` does not support `\textcite` with author-date citations, so you'll have to stick to `\parencite`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=windycity]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{baggio,
  Author  = {R. Baggio and M. van Lambalgen and P. Hagoort},
  Journal = {Journal of Memory and Language},
  Pages   = {36--53},
  Title   = {Computing and Recomputing Discourse Models: An {ERP} Study},
  Volume  = {59},
  Year    = {2008},
}
@book{anderson,
  Address   = {Mahwah, NJ},
  Author    = {J. R. Anderson},
  Publisher = {Lawrence Erlbaum Associates},
  Title     = {The Architecture of Cognition},
  Year      = {1983},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{baggio} and \parencite{anderson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Baggio, Lambalgen, and Hagoort 2008) and (Anderson 1983)]

Comment: Sir, you are so kind and so much helpfull....I'll check your suggestion and get back....

Comment: Sir, `biblatex-chicago note` is the exact one, what I'm searching, thanks a lot....